# How to obtain links using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to obtain links using selenium from an e-commerce website. I'm a literally noob at web-scraping. So I'm open to any type of suggestions.

So this is the basic structure. Some of `<tr>` tags contain `<href>` which I want.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
```

> What I have tried :

```
x1 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tbody')

for x in x1:
    print(x.text)
```

For some reason, this is fetching everything on the page, not only the things I want. Maybe that's because, there's another `<tbody>` tag at the start of the code and it covers everything in it.

My Question is:
How can I grab links from the `<tbody>` tag that I want?

Comment: What else identifies that tbody? If there are multiple tbodies you might need a more complicated selector. Try recording it with something that generates selectors like the chrome devtools "copy css selector" feature or [Testim Playground](https://www.testim.io/playwright-recorder/)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for sharing your views, I've added a photo, can you look into it? Let's see if it make things more clear for you

Comment: @QasimKhan Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

x1 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tbody')

for x in x1:
print(x.get_attribute('href'))